# How to insert png image in latex?

Tags: windows, latex

```
\begin{figure}[p]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{Architecture.png}
\graphicspath{ {D:/PROJECT/Architecture} }
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.png}
\end{figure}
```

This is what I have tried for. But I couldn't see any image just the name Architecture.png is displaying. Can anyone please correct me. Thank you.

Comment: Did you include `\usepackage{graphicx}` and (maybe relevant) `\graphicspath{ {path/to/image/} }`?

Comment: Drop the `\graphicspath` and `\DeclareGraphicsExtensions` from your `figure`. Instead, you must have a `draft` option specified somewhere in your document. Check `\documentclass[...,draft,...]{<class>}` or `\usepackage[...,draft,...]{graphicx}`. Remove that.